# Writing Dynamic SQL Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, dynamic-sql

I am very new to Microsoft Access.

I would like to select a column from a table based on the value of a parameter (i.e. my table has columns x, y and z and I have a `chosencol` parameter which is set by the user using a dropdown.

I can select one / all of the columns using a select command, however, I would like to do this using my parameter `chosencol` instead.

Having read around, I have found a number of references to using the `SET` and `EXEC` commands, however, entering them into the SQL command in Access just yields errors.

Please could someone advise me as to how I go about implementing a dynamic-sql query in Access (in fine detail as I think I am writing the commands in the wrong place at the moment...)

Comment: You might wanna look into DoCmd.RunSQL if you don't want to add a new Q to your DB each time you run it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I created an example table in Access.

[image: Here is your table in Access]

Next, I created an example form to query your value. The dropdown is called 'chosencol'. Select a value from the Column Select dropdown and press the "Lookup Value" button.

[image: Here is your Access form]

Here is the code under the "Lookup Value" button's On Click event. A SQL statement is dynamically built with the column you chose. The column is renamed to [FieldName] to that it can by referenced.

```
Private Sub btnLookup_Click()
    Dim rsLookup As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "select " & chosencol.Value & " as [FieldName] from Table1 where ID=1"
    rsLookup.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    If rsLookup.EOF = False Then
        txtValue.SetFocus
        txtValue.Text = rsLookup![FieldName]
    End If
    rsLookup.Close
End Sub
```

When the button is pushed, the value from whatever column you selected will be returned.  For this simple example, I'm always returning row 1's data.

Comment: Thanks this is just what I needed and you addressed the specific of the question posed - i.e. where to put the code :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that in straight SQL.  However, you can create the SQL string in VBA code and save it as a query.

```
CurrentDB.CreateQueryDef("MyQueryName", "SELECT " & chosencol & " FROM MyTable")
```

Now, MyQueryName will be a permanent query in your database and can be referenced wherever you want.

If chosencol is a multi-select dropdown, you'll have to read the selected values into an array and then write the array to one concatenated string and use that instead.