# select in select sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to create a sql query. The column name that I want, it's in another table. I wrote this query.

```
SELECT (SELECT FieldName From TableGENQuest WHERE ID = 1)
FROM TableGEN
WHERE strSO = 'RV12648-01';
```

[image: My TableGENQuest table's FieldName column]

[image: my TableGEN table's strGEN1 column]

I want to get the data from the strGEN1 columns using the FieldName column of the TableGENQuest table.That is data I want `No significant transportation damage observed`.

Comment: Do a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: show the two tables data

Comment: Most likely you need to use JOIN. Do these tables have any common fields?

Comment: Please, define _"it doesn't work."_

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a useful error message or problem statement. We can't fix "doesn't work" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that is "not working", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code? It would help us also to know the table definitions and some sample input/output data. As others have mentioned, it's possible that this should be solved using a JOIN, but it's hard to be sure without knowing more information.

Comment: Ok. This situation seems potentially to be the result of a poorly designed schema. It's not usual to need to dynamically select a column name based on a row in another table. You still haven't shown us all the info (e.g. strSO column is missing), but it seems like maybe you are using a different strGENxxx column for each reference ID? If you have something dynamic like IDs then you should be storing data for each ID in _rows_, not columns. Then this kind of issue would not arise.

Comment: To accomplish what you want using your current data structure you'd need some dynamically generated SQL, and the only way to do that in Access is to write a VBA script which creates and executes the correct query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093543/writing-dynamic-sql-statement for example

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: Your request is not possible using MS Access SQL alone.**

You will need to use VBA to open a recordset containing the content of the table `TableGENQuest` and construct an appropriate SQL statement whilst iterating over the records held by such recordset.

For example:

```vb
Sub GenerateQuery()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT FieldName FROM TableGENQuest WHERE ID = 1")

    With rst
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do Until .EOF
                sql = sql & "[" & !FieldName & "], "
                .MoveNext
            Loop
            sql = "select " & Left(sql, Len(sql) - 2) & " from TableGEN WHERE strSO = 'RV12648-01';"
        End If
        .Close
    End With

    If sql <> vbNullString Then dbs.CreateQueryDef "OutputQuery", sql
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above will generate a query defined in the current database with a SQL statement selecting the fields whose fieldnames are sourced using the SQL:

```
SELECT FieldName FROM TableGENQuest WHERE ID = 1
```

The difficulty and convoluted nature of this method indicates that your database is poorly designed: the field names themselves should instead appear as rows within another table.

Comment: @Mustafa how was anyone supposed to know that from your question? That's the first time you've mentioned it. It helps if you tell people the real problem from the start. But anyway, the concept will be exactly the same, you just write the same idea using java syntax. Have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT b.FieldName FROM TableGEN a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableGENQuest b
ON a.ID=b.ID
WHERE a.strSO = 'RV12648-01'
AND b.ID=1
```

**OR**

```
SELECT a.strSO,b.FieldName,b.ID
FROM TableGEN a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT FieldName,ID From TableGENQuest WHERE ID = 1
)
b 
ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE strSO = 'RV12648-01'
```

Try This Query...or can change Join Type...

Comment: `ON a.ID=b.ID` ...where's your evidence that both tables contain "ID" fields, or that they map to each other? We only know about one ID field, so your code is just guesswork. And if you read OP's description more closely, you'll see that it's unlikely to be the case that they match. OP is actually look for a dynamic SQL solution, which isn't possible without VBA code.

Comment: `SELECT b.FieldName` ...this will just print the string "strGEN01". It won't print the data from the desired column named strGEN01 in the other table.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT TableGENQuest.FieldName 
FROM TableGEN, TableGENQuest 
WHERE TableGENQuest.ID=1 AND WHERE strSO = 'RV12648-01';
```

Comment: Read your query again.

Comment: you can't have two WHERE keywords, and you should use standard JOIN syntax. Comma-separated joins are a legacy thing, no longer recommended.