# Use a Variable in a Query SQL

Tags: variables, ms-access-2010

I have a database with my media in it. And a query with the following line:

```
WHERE (((LPofCD.LPofCD) = MyKeus()))

Public Keus As String
Function MyKeus() As String
    MyKeus = Keus
End Function
```

In a Form I can choose: Keus=1 for LP, 2 for CD, ect. This is working fine.

Now I also want to choose >0 : so I can select ALL the items.
This is what I tried:
I fill 'Keus' with a part of the sql WHERE, like this:

```
Keus = [Forms]![Output_Catalog]![Kies_Medium]
Keus = "((([1_Medium].LPofCD_ID)=" & Keus & "))"

WHERE MyKeus()
```

But this does not work.

Anybody that can give me a solution?

Comment: you would need dynamic sql for such a think see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093543/writing-dynamic-sql-statement

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
make the selection not in the query, but in the DoCmd OpenReport, like this:

```
If MyKeus() > 0 Then
  DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="Catalog_Band_Medium", _
    View:=acPreview, _
    FilterName:="Catalog_Band_Medium_Query", _
    WhereCondition:="[1_Medium].LPofCD_ID = MyKeus()", _
    WindowMode:=acWindowNormal
  DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "Catalog_Band_Medium"
  DoCmd.Maximize
Else
  DoCmd.OpenReport "Catalog_Band_Medium", acPreview, acWindowNormal
  DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "Catalog_Band_Medium"
  DoCmd.Maximize
End If
```

So, the problem I had is solved, after a long search and tried the different possibilities.